B777-300 secure cockpit door flaps
B777-300 secure cockpit door has two flaps for rapid decompression pressure going from cockpit to cabin.
What system is used internally to release the flaps? Subsidiary question: can the system be reactivated after decompression event or test, or is there any fusible part that needs to be changed?

This one is the sensor to trigger the opening of the door itself (from cabin to cockpit). For the other way, the air is going through those flaps I'm interested in.

This is not a direct answer for the 777. I don't know if Boeing is going to disclose the exact mechanism used today, for security reasons. Still they filed a patent shedding some light on how it could work.
From the patent:


Each panel is locked by an articulated hook (428 and 432)
The hook is locked by a pin (438) in a hole.
The pin is controlled by the pressure sensor (436).

When the pressure difference between door sides exceeds a threshold, the pin is recessed, releasing the hook, the panel can swing in both directions freely. The full process is fast enough to be compatible with an explosive decompression.
More:

Boeing patent.
Boeing 757/767 flight deck door.

In the second article it is said the panel can be closed/reset after the sensor has been triggered.
From what I read, there are single-plate panels and panels made of multiple small slats, protected by a grid to prevent any intrusion when the panel is open.
